# UserLogin Program in java I could not find my mistake.Can you plz help me out

Tags: java

When I enter "helloworld" as username the program returns username is incorrect. I could not understand what my problem is.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        String userName, sys_userName = "helloworld";
        int passWord, sys_passWord = 12345;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
        
        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        userName = scan.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        passWord = scan.nextInt();
        
        if ((userName == sys_userName) && (passWord == sys_passWord)) {
            
            System.out.println("Welcome!");
        }
        
        else if ((userName != sys_userName) && (passWord == sys_passWord)) {
            
            System.out.println("Username is incorrect!");
        }
        
        else if ((userName == sys_userName) && (passWord != sys_passWord)) {
            
            System.out.println("Password is incorrect!");
        }
        
        else if ((userName != sys_userName) && (passWord != sys_passWord)) {
            
            System.out.println("All infos are incorrect!");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparison of values within objects you need to use `.equals()` method. By comparing `==` within objects Java compares memory addresses.

So the solution for you replace `==` with `.equals()`.

```
if ((sys_userName.equals(username)) && (passWord == sys_passWord)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome!");
}
```

The same for the other `if` branches.